# redelivery-delay-multiplier in hornetq 2.3.0 Final is not respected

Tags: hornetq

This is my setup :

```
<address-settings>
      <!--default for catch all-->
      <address-setting match="#">
         <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
         <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
         <!-- 240000 = 4 min-->
         <redelivery-delay>30000</redelivery-delay>
         <!--<expiry-delay></expiry-delay>-->
         <redelivery-delay-multiplier>20.0</redelivery-delay-multiplier> 
         <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
         <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes>       
         <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
         <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
      </address-setting>
   </address-settings>
```

I see in my logs that 4 minutes delay is respected but it does not respect setup redelivery-delay-multiplier. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup max-redelivery-delay to take it effect, as the max-redelivery-delay's default is redelivery-delay

```
   <address-settings>
      <!--default for catch all-->
      <address-setting match="#">
         <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
         <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
         <!-- 240000 = 4 min-->
         <redelivery-delay>24000</redelivery-delay>
         <!-- 2400000 = 40 min .. or whatever you like -->
         **<max-redelivery-delay>2400000</max-redelivery-delay>**
         <redelivery-delay-multiplier>20.0</redelivery-delay-multiplier> 
         <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
         <max-size-bytes>104857600</max-size-bytes>       
         <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
         <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
      </address-setting>
   </address-settings>
```

I'm changing this behavior on future versions (2.4.0+) through this issue tracker:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-1263

Comment: I'm adding a JIRA: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-1263

I'm going to default max-redelivery-delay = delivery-delay * 10...

Any other suggestions to the default change?

Comment: Hi Clebet, I tried that on my embedded HornetQ with JBoss 6.1.1.Final but got configuration errors saying max-redelivery-delay is not expected. How do I know what version of HornetQ is running with my JBoss 6.1.1.Final? Thanks